# Entity framework select entities bigger than DateTime (plus the entity before)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection of entities that has (among other things) a DateTime value. I would like to query the DB (with Entity Framework) for all entities bigger than a specific DateTime and also get the closests value back in time from this DateTime. The time points are not evenly distributed and I only want to make one db roundtrip.

Ex: 
    [{T = 1}, {T = 2}, {T = 3}, {T = 4}]

So... if I query the db for an entity with a timevalue bigger than or equeal to T = 3, I also want to get the T = 2 value back. That is

Result:
[{T = 2}, {T = 3}, {T = 4}]

Is this possible? If not, is it possible in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return two groups

```
from o in db.Orders
group o by o.T >= value into g
select g.Key ? g.OrderBy(x => x.T) : 
               g.OrderByDescending(x => x.T).Take(1)
```

One group will contain entities which have `T >= value` and another group will have entity before (if any).

**UPDATE** as @Gert Arnold correctly pointed, this query will work with Linq to SQL, but will not work with Entity Framework. Instead of grouping you should use union of two sub queries:

```
db.Orders.Where(o => o.T >= value)
         .Union(db.Orders.Where(o => o.T < value)
                         .OrderByDescending(o => o.T)
                         .Take(1));
```

Comment: Nice solution, but EF won't allow it (something like "Nested query not allowed"). The nearest possible thing would be a Union of two queries (`>=`, and `<` with `Take(1)`).

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for note! I verified this query in LinqPad with Linq to SQL. I definitely need to check it in EF now :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Haven't tested it yet but it looks fine. By the way, do you have any idea on how this query performs compared to if I implemented it as a stored procedure?

Comment: @user842077 stored procedure definitely will be faster, but you will spend more time on writing and maintaining it. I think you should optimize performance only when you have some problems with it